# Python setup tools installation error using ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, ubuntu

I am trying to run the command sudo python3 setup.py install in the research directory of TensorFlow models but I am getting the following error:

```
File "/tmp/easy_install-7odqdand/matplotlib-3.2.0rc3/setup.py", line 136
raise IOError(f"Failed to download jquery-ui.  Please download "
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: They appeared to have forgotten a `)` at the end of that line. Go into the file listed in the path and fix it, or wait for them to realize their mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely using a version of python less than Python3.6.
f-strings are used and supported since then apparently. 
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/17075#issuecomment-611190672

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to upgrade python just upgrade matplotlib to version 2.1.0 which is the minimum requirement for tensorflow object detection API. I just did that and been able to install Tensorflow Object detection API on Ubuntu 16, which comes with python 3.5.